# manage.py doesn't be shown in project directory

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

I create one project and here is the folder structure:

```
mysite
    mysite
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

The manage.py is missing.

I am using Django version `1.4.20` and python version `2.6.6`.

Is there anyone who has the same problem before?

Thank you.

Comment: That's...odd. What steps did you take when initializing your project?

Comment: Also, manage.py is basically the same from project to project. You can grab a copy of the default from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py